# Retrieve the column separator used by fread

Tags: r, data.table, delimiter, csv

`fread` from the `data.table` package can generally automatically determine the column separator (`sep`) when reading a file.

For example, here `fread` automatically detects `|` as column delimiter:

```
library(data.table)
fread(paste(c("A|1", "B|2", "C|3"), collapse = "\n"))
#    V1 V2
# 1:  A  1
# 2:  B  2
# 3:  C  3
```

But how can I retrieve the column separator which eventually was used by `fread` (here, the `|`)?

Comment: Have you checked the `verbose` argument in `fread`? `fread(paste(c("A|1", "B|2", "C|3"), collapse = "\n"), verbose = TRUE)` - "Detecting sep ... '|'". You may consider to make your question more specific. You currently have quite a few different (and broad) questions. It's also up to you to provide a _minimal_ example. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, this was honestly my primary question, and knowing this negates the rest.  Also, I figured it was as simple as some attribute, so I didn't include an example.  Thanks! If you want to make yours an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: You should always try to include a MCVE. In general, it makes people much more likely to help when they have toy data to play with and verify their code.

Comment: Yes, I usually do for more complex questions.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Henrik mentions, this info is printed to the console if `verbose = TRUE` is chosen. You can capture the info printed about the separator with

```
library(magrittr)
example <- paste(c("A|1", "B|2", "C|3"), collapse = "\n")
capture.output(fread(example, verbose = TRUE) %>% {NULL}) %>% 
    .[grepl('Detecting sep', .)]


#[1] "Detecting sep ... '|'"
```

You could also just implement your own delimiter finder based on the description of how `fread` finds the delimiter:

> Defaults to the first character in the set `[,\t |;:]` that exists on
>   line `autostart` outside quoted (`""`) regions

Comment: Nice answer. I tried it without the `%>% {NULL}` and it still seemed to work..? The OP/user could also add a step `%>% sub("^.* '(.)'$", "\\1", x = .)` to pull out the character.

Comment: @Frank Without `%>% {NULL}` the entire `data.table` is put in the output of `capture.output(...)`

Comment: D'oh, right, thanks. In practice, I guess you'd want the data as well as the separator so `capture.output(dat <- fread(example, verbose = TRUE)) %>% ...` and not need the NULL (unless I'm missing something still).

Comment: Yes, that's probably the better way.